# How can I get millisecond-level accuracy timestamps on screenshots (vlc)?

Tags: command-line, java, vlc-media-player, screen-capture

I'm currently using

```
rt.exec("C:\\VLC\\vlc screen:// --dshow-vdev=screen-capture-recorder --dshow-fps=10 -I dummy --dummy-quiet --rate=1 --video-filter=scene --vout=dummy --scene-format=jpg --scene-ratio=1 --scene-prefix=snap --scene-path=" + path +" --scene-prefix=scap vlc://quit");
```

to take my screencaptures. I [read](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Snapshots/) that you can insert "$T" in the scene prefix to get second-level accuracy for screencaps, but I end up with titles like "scap$T00001.jpg."

It looks like other people have had the same problem and it was [fixed?](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/2955).

However, I tried it on 3 different versions of VLC (most recent, 2.0 and 1.0) and none of them worked for me.

Can you suggest either

- A workaround to get millisecond level timestamps?
- A way to take the screenshots in atomic time?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution to this?